# How to retrieve data from datagrid combo box using wpf?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

// Hi actually i am a newbie to the wpf and here i am facing a problem . I unable to retrieve values or data from data grid using a combo box and when ever i am trying to retrieve im getting a error "Object set to an instance" here is my code please check and help is appreciated

```
//XAML code :

<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="packagetype2" TextBinding="{Binding Uom}"  x:Name="cmb_pktype" ></DataGridComboBoxColumn>


//c# code:


DataSet ds1 = uomc.fillcombo();

cmb_pktype.ItemsSource = ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
cmb_pktype.DisplayMemberPath = ds1.Tables[0].Columns["Name"].ToString();
cmb_pktype.SelectedValuePath = ds1.Tables[0].Columns["Id"].ToString();



//when i am retrieveing the data like as below 


string type = (dgv_uomconversionmapping.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(dgv_uomconversionmapping.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text;

    enter code here

//This retrieving process is working for data grid textblock column 
//as this way how can i read the datagrid combobox column
```

Comment: bind combobox selected value and get it from there

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `myComboBox SelectedItem={Binding myComboBoxSelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` in your ComboBox xaml.

MyComboBoxSelectedItem should then be an exposed public property in your viewModel which raises the PropertyChanged event from INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Something like this:

```
  private string _myComboBoxSelectedItem;
    public string myComboBoxSelectedItem
    {
        get { return _myComboBoxSelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _myComboBoxSelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("myComboBoxSelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

This way when the user makes a selection from the ComboBox, the value is persisted to the property.

Answer (score 0):

Use combobox  and change your xaml code to this

```
`<ComboBox Name="combobox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

`

Comment: just change DataGridComboBoxColumn  to combobox and try